# Sorting the output of a function to display from High to Low

Tags: c, arrays, function, typedef, qsort

I have a struct, defined as this:

```
typedef struct structure
{
char names[20];
int scores[4];
float average;
char letter;
} stuff;
```

And from that struct created this array:

```
stuff everything[13];
```

Later, a function called with:

```
display(everything);
```

displays to the screen a basic chart that displays 13 Names, 13 test1s, 13 test2s, 13 test3s, 13 test4s, 13 averages, and 13 letter grades, in no order. For reference, the function looks like this:

```
void display(stuff *everything)
{
int q = 0;

printf("\n\n Name \t\t E1 \t E2 \t E3 \t E4 \t Avg \t Grade");
for(q=0; q<13; q++)
{
printf("\n %s \t %d \t %d \t %d \t %d \t %.2f \t %c", 
everything[q].names,
everything[q].scores[0],
everything[q].scores[1],
everything[q].scores[2], 
everything[q].scores[3],
everything[q].average,
everything[q].letter);
}
return;
}
```

I would like to to take the averages and compare them against each other so that when it displays to the screen, the first result is the highest average, and it goes down from there. I'm pretty sure I'd be using 'qsort()' but I'm having extreme difficulties understanding the syntax for it. Some help with qsort and how do use it in this particular instance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not everything is about syntax. There's the semantics, too. What have you tried? Do you know about function pointers? Which book are you reading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`man 3 qsort()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html). If you read this, you will be able to use it. The only thing you need is a proper comparator function that returns the order of the two elements given as its arguments:

```
int comp_avg(const void *p1, const void *p2)
{
    const stuff *s1 = p1, *s2 = p2;
    return (s1->average > s2->average) - (s1->average < s2->average);
}
```

Then you can sort the array easily:

```
qsort(
    everything,
    sizeof(everything) / sizeof(everything[0]),
    sizeof(everything[0]),
    comp_avg
);
```

Comment: @Xerinos: make sure you **understand** the answer. Don't copy-paste.

Comment: From the look of the questions he/she has asked in the past, you're asking a little too much... If he/she wanted to understand anything, he/she would have known the answer to this question from the C bible. As philosophical food for thought: What should I look for when judging whether or not someone *wants to learn*?

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Well, that's a hard question. An approximation with constant `O(1)` computational complexity would be to simply always assume "OP doesn't want to learn and just copy-pastes", because that's what 99.99% of askers on Stack Overflow does.

Comment: I'm sure the heuristics you use can be described if you give it some further thought. I'll be most interested to hear what you come up with :)

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour Well, stay active on SO for half a year and you'll see what I mean! ;-)